Removal of Special Character NUL from SQL Output File
I am creating a pipe delimited file to be sent to an outside entity.  My source table that I use to construct my query contains some null values in some of the columns of the source table.  My export file cannot contain these null values so am using the Replace function to remove the Null values with '' (single quotes, no spaces).
My resulting file contains the control character NUL where I tried to replace null values with ''.
I am using the bulk copy command with queryout to create the file.  Does anyone know how I can create the output without the control character while eliminating the NULL values?
,REPLACE(ltrim(rtrim(left(tenroll.Member_address1,30))),''NULL'','''') as Address

above is a code snippet from my select statement.  It is saved as a variable which is the reason for the additional single quotes.
I am expecting NULL to disappear with no spaces.   Instead it is replaced with the control character NUL. Which is causing issues with formatting on the recipient end.

Please tag the rdbms you are using

@DaleK, i would assume its SQLite: its allows NUL characters

https://www.sqlite.org/nulinstr.html , also, if you need to replace NULL value with something else check COALESCE function

@PowerMouse that's not the point, we shouldn't have to deduce it, questions should contain all relevant info.

REPLACE(YourValue, CHAR(0), '')

Instead of the "Replace" function, you can also try out the "ISNULL" function.
ISNULL(ltrim(rtrim(left(tenroll.Member_address1,30))), '''') as Address

